# KendoUI 100% stacked column chart not showing correctly

Tags: php, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a Kendo UI 100% stacked column chart, created with the PHP wrappers, binding to a remote data source, but it shows the data incorrectly.

The PHP wrapper generates the following jQuery script:

```
jQuery(function(){jQuery("#CRMIssueQuery").kendoChart({
    "title":{
        "text":"Nyert \u00e9s vesztett ig\u00e9nyek ar\u00e1nya forr\u00e1sonk\u00e9nt"
    },
    "seriesDefaults":{
        "type":"column",
        "stack":{"type":"100%"},
        "style":"smooth"
    },
    "legend":{"position":"bottom"},
    "dataSource":{
        "transport":{
            "read":{
                "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/g4s_portal\/?page=chart-data&mode=chart-data&w=1&id=17&type=column&from=2018.03.27&to=2018.04.26",
                "type":"POST",
                "dataType":"json"
            }
        }
    },
    "categoryAxis":[{
        "labels":{"rotation":-45},
        "crosshair":{"visible":false},
        "majorGridLines":{"visible":false},
        "majorTicks":{"visible":true}
    }],
    "valueAxis":[{
        "majorGridLines":{"visible":true}
    }],
    "pdf":{
        "fileName":"CRMIssueQuery_2018_04_26_10_04_18.pdf",
        "proxyURL":"http:\/\/localhost\/g4s_portal\/?page=chart-data&mode=pdf&w=1"
    },
    "tooltip":{
        "visible":true,
        "format":"{0}",
        "template":"#= series.name #: #= value #"
    },
    "chartArea":{
        "background":"transparent"
    },
    "dataBound":OnDataBoundChart,
    "series":[
        {"field":"Nyert","categoryField":"Name","name":"Nyert"},
        {"field":"Vesztett","categoryField":"Name","name":"Vesztett"}
    ]
});});
```

This is the data I get from the remote datasource:

```
[{"Name":"Belső megkeresés","Nyert":"69","Vesztett":"2"},
 {"Name":"E-mail","Nyert":"8","Vesztett":"13"},
 {"Name":"Honlap","Nyert":"4","Vesztett":"6"},
 {"Name":"Telefon","Nyert":"59","Vesztett":"14"}]
```

And here is the chart I get:
[image]

It seems, that the first data value, called "Nyert" is always at 100%, and the second data value "Vesztett" is starts at 100% and grows in the rate of the first data value, or the sum of the two.

Probably the given remote data's structure is the problem, which is fine, because I have the control over that too, but I can't seem to find any example for the required structure for theese type of charts.

Here is a [Kendo Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ATeTiYeQ) with the desired outcome. The only difference is, that here the data cames from local binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using integer values instead of string ones.
That should do the trick:

```
[{"Name":"Belső megkeresés","Nyert":69,"Vesztett":2},
{"Name":"E-mail","Nyert":8,"Vesztett":13},
{"Name":"Honlap","Nyert":4,"Vesztett":6},
{"Name":"Telefon","Nyert":59,"Vesztett":14}]
```